# Is it possible to get the value in a lambda in HTML and use it in a razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to get the value in

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.gender)
```

and use a razor and do an `if...then` statement? The value of the `item.gender` is either **1** or **0** and I'm planning to use a razor with an `if...then` statement so I can change the display to `Female` or `Male` instead of **1** or **0**.

Comment: `@{ if (Model.gender == 1) { //..do something here } }` should work. Although if you're wanting to still use the DisplayFor syntax then you can always make a custom display template for this field. http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm

Answer (score 2):

Something like the below  should work, you test whether the `Gender` is `0` or `1` and then decide what to display

```
@{if (Model.gender == 0){
         @Html.Display("Female")}
      else{
         @Html.Display("Male")}
    }
```

OR depending on what you want to do the below should also give you further ideas on how you could display

```
@Html.Display(Model.gender == 0?"Female":"Male")
```